# Laravel 5.5 The page has expired due to inactivity error while sending form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'am using laravel 5.5 and it gives me that "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again." This is awkward because I never encounter this error. Same codes but different laravel version..

My form;

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'admin/save-social']) !!}
{{ Form::label('pinterest', 'Pinterest;', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::text('pinterest', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
{{ Form::label('linkedn', 'Linkedn;', ['class' => 'control-label'])}}
{{ Form::text('linkedn', null, ['class' => 'form-control'])}}
{{ Form::label('facebook', 'Facebook;', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::text('facebook', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::label('twitter', 'Twitter;', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::text('twitter', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::label('instagram', 'İnstagram;', ['class' => 'control-label']) }}
{{ Form::text('instagram', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block']) }}
{!! Form::close()!!}
```

And `config/session.php`

```
<?php

return [
    'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'file'),
    'lifetime' => 120,
    'expire_on_close' => false,
    'encrypt' => false,
    'files' => storage_path('framework/sessions'),
    'connection' => null,
    'table' => 'sessions',
    'store' => null,
    'lottery' => [2, 100],
    'cookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        str_slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
    'secure' => env('SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE', false),
    'http_only' => true,
    'same_site' => null,
];
```

Comment: What is the session driver that you use ? Check in `config/session.php`

Comment: It looks to me like you are missing the {{ csrf_field() }} in the form you're trying to submit. Can you confirm it's there?

Comment: i am using laravelcollective's forms.. that forms contain csrf token

Comment: This message appears if season has expired or form csrf field changed

Comment: Can you provide your code please? (session.php) and your form?

Comment: Edited, and added form and session.php

Comment: @HasanTıngır can you try these commands :
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear

Comment: it works.. thank you :)

Comment: @HasanTıngır ok i glad to hear that , i have added it as an answer so that everyone can see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since these commands has solved your problem in the comments i should write it as an answer . Try these commands and start your form again

```
 php artisan cache:clear
 php artisan config:clear 
 php artisan route:clear 
 php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using laravel collective for  forms builder.

Probably your issue is associate with CSRF Protection (https://laravelcollective.com/docs/master/html#csrf-protection).

Please check the above link and ensure that you include CSRF based on method or explicit Form::token();

Comment: Another point is that Laravelcollective maybe not is available for laravel 5.5. You can check this issue from GitHub and find a workaround for collective in Laravel 5.5  https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/364

Answer (score 0):

Another point is that Laravelcollective maybe not is available for laravel 5.5. You can check this issue from GitHub and find a workaround for collective in Laravel 5.5  https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/issues/364

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following statements:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

It worked for me. Enjoy